# Calculate position on the edge of a polygon given a LatLng location and bearing

Tags: javascript, java, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gis

I have a LatLng location (the current location of the user) and a bearing (from the centre of the polygon). I know the location is currently inside the polygon, and I can get the bearing from the centre of the polygon and the user's location.

I need to know the point on the edge of the polygon given the bearing from the centre. I envisage this as being an intersection between a line from the centre and the edge of the polygon, but I don't see any helpers in Google Maps API or any examples online.

This will be written in Java using Google Maps SDK, but I would appreciate a solution in any language, especially Javascript.

The following crudely drawn diagram illustrates the problem (hopefully) more clearly.

[image: Polygon with user location and centre]

Here's a jsfiddle with (not the) centre position and a user location.

http://jsfiddle.net/joshkopecek/rh9mzyoa/2/

```
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(22.7964, 79.8456),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
  });

  var coords = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(18.979026, 72.949219), //Mumbai
    new google.maps.LatLng(28.613459, 77.255859), //Delhi
    new google.maps.LatLng(22.512557, 88.417969), //Kolkata
    new google.maps.LatLng(12.940322, 77.607422), //Bengaluru
  ];

  metros = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: coords,
    strokeColor: "#0000FF",
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: "#0000FF",
    fillOpacity: 0.26
  });

  userPos = new google.maps.LatLng(21.1952534, 81.2680344);
  userMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: userPos,
    map: map
  });

  centrePos = new google.maps.LatLng(22.049832, 78.9022019);

  centreMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: centrePos,
    map: map
  });

  heading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(centrePos, userPos);

  metros.setMap(map);

  var metros;
  var userMarker;
  var centreMarker;
  var heading;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs you could use `isLocationOnEdge(point:LatLng, poly:Polygon|Polyline, tolerance?:number)` which will return if a given point is on the edge of a polygon, within a certain tolerance.  You could use `computeOffset` with your heading to test points along a path until you find what you need.

As an aside, any real/intensive spatial analysis I have not had much luck with client-side technologies.  My preferred method would usually be a server call backed by a spatial database like PostGIS that I can then offload all the analysis to.  You could look at ESRI's JavaScript api though, if you were so inclined.

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful. I think `computeOffset` is probably what we were looking for, but this will only give us a reading within a given tolerance. i.e. 10m from centre of polygon with an accuracy of 1m. The tradeoff will be the step/tolerance distance within the iteration, between computation time and accuracy. 

This _must_ be done on the mobile device, in real time as it's going to update as a user's position changes when they walk. I guess we'll have to test how expensive it will be to do this with 100ms location updates and progressive iterations.

Comment: I had another idea as well.  If possible, it would probably be much faster and easier to work in a local projection, e.g. UTM or State Planar if you are in the U.S.  This way all your calculations are just simple Euclidean geometry that you could probably just do yourself.  Of course, if you need to support locations worldwide this is probably way more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: unfortunately we work with content all over Europe, so can't really go with a US-specific solution! Thanks for the thought anyway.